# What is the default encoding of DOMDocument?

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

When we do `$dom = new DOMDocument();`, what is the default encoding of this file ?

Comment: Unspecified? libxml won't push out an encoding marker unless it has a reason to. Really depends on what it [was feeded](http://www.xmlsoft.org/encoding.html). Why not just use the $encoding parameter and be sure?

Comment: I tried to do : `$dom=new DOMDocument(); echo $dom->$encoding;` but PHP says that `encoding` is undefined

Comment: It's set from the `DOMDocument::__construct(NULL, $encoding)` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be no encoding if the document is empty !
Thanks all for help !